# how to style display div over the other div

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

My block of code

```
<div class="form-row">
 <div class="col">
   <div class="search-contributor-box">
     <p>
       <input type="text" class="form-control search-contributor"
           placeholder="Contributor" name="contributor" id="contributor"
           value="Add contributor" autocomplete="off">
     </p>
     <div class="sub-search-contributor sub-panel" style="display: none;">
         <p class="lead" style="text-align:center;color:#a9a9a9;">
           <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
           Looking for someone
         </p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col">
   <p>
     <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="role" name="role">
         <option value="developer" selected>Developer</option>
         <option value="leader">Leader</option>
     </select>
   </p>
 </div>
 <div class="col">
   <p>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Salary" id="salary"
             name="salary" value="">
   </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

It produce me like this:

[image]

how to style ,to get display result `Looking for someone` over other other div

Comment: do you want another div over this div MIR

Comment: this div `<div class="sub-search-contributor sub-panel"`

Comment: Add all of the code you hav used. Remove `style="display: none;"` and see there is no element under it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i dont misunderstanding, try to set

```
style={position: 'absolute'}
```

in the div u want to over